# priorize visible content php html

Tags: javascript, php, html, view, visible

I have a site called www.anetoi.com and I want to prioritize visible content. PageSpeed Insights says:

> Your page requires additional network round trips to render the above-the-fold content. For best performance, reduce the amount of HTML needed to render above-the-fold content.
>   The entire HTML response was not sufficient to render the above-the-fold content. This usually indicates that additional resources, loaded after HTML parsing, were required to render above-the-fold content. Prioritize visible content that is needed for rendering above-the-fold by including it directly in the HTML response.
>   Only about 66% of the final above-the-fold content could be rendered with the full HTML response.

In my home page I am adding all the HTML in a single variable and I echo this variable in order to print all my HTML at once. I also have slide bars that I added at the end of each HTML in order to show the visible content.

The problem is still there and I can't find what's wrong. I am really stuck with this.

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Look @ the network tab. You have a blocking request to facebook in your site header. Browser has to wait for it to complete before loading the rest of the page

Comment: From the response, it sounds like you're doing some Javascript / AJAX / client side fetching that comes after the page is loaded.  Looking at the site you listed, there are multiple javascript inclusions and I'm getting jquery ajax pings every 5 seconds from a script called `online_offline_detect.js`.

Comment: I think online_offline_detect.js does not affect the visible content. If i remove the facebook like box will solve my problems?